# Is there a cost to do a "S3GetObjectMetadataRequest"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

before downloading a file from AWS s3, I would like to double check that the file is really there - the right way seems is to call S3GetObjectMetadataRequest - however, does this count as a get/list/...?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it will be considered as a GET, and you will have to pay the "request pricing".

Request pricing is detailed here: 
http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

However this will be negligible compared to the Data transfer (real download) pricing. So you will be better off issuing this request (and pay) before deciding to download the file (if that was your confusion).

Comment: You can get the metadata with an http HEAD request, which isn't technically considered a GET (the bucket logs, if enabled, show them differently) but the pricing is the same, as you mention.  And, of course, there's no data transfer charge between EC2 and S3 in the same region. (+1)

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot ! (+1 your comment)